# Disable click outside of angular material dialog area to close the dialog (With Angular Version 4.0+)

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog, angular-material

I am currently working on password reset page of an Angular 4 project. We are using Angular Material to create the dialog, however, when the client clicks out of the dialog, it will close automatically. Is there a way to avoid the dialog close until our code side call "close" function? Or how should I create an *unclosable* modal?

Answer (score 529, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

1. In the method that opens the dialog, pass in the following configuration option `disableClose` as the second parameter in `MatDialog#open()` and set it to `true`:

   ```ts
   export class AppComponent {
     constructor(private dialog: MatDialog){}
     openDialog() {
       this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, { disableClose: true });
     }
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively, do it in the dialog component itself.

   ```ts
   export class DialogComponent {
     constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>){
       dialogRef.disableClose = true;
     }
   }
   ```

Here's what you're looking for:

[image: disableClose property in material.angular.io]

And here's a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dialog-disable-close-so)

---

## Other use cases

Here's some other use cases and code snippets of how to implement them.

### Allow <kbd>esc</kbd> to close the dialog but disallow clicking on the backdrop to close the dialog

As what @MarcBrazeau said in the comment below my answer, you can allow the <kbd>esc</kbd> key to close the modal but still disallow clicking outside the modal. Use this code on your dialog component:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-third-dialog',
  templateUrl: './third-dialog.component.html'
})
export class ThirdDialogComponent {
  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ThirdDialogComponent>) {      
}
  @HostListener('window:keyup.esc') onKeyUp() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

---

### Prevent <kbd>esc</kbd> from closing the dialog but allow clicking on the backdrop to close

> P.S. This is an answer which originated from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51015306), where the demo was based on this answer.

To prevent the <kbd>esc</kbd> key from closing the dialog but allow clicking on the backdrop to close, I've adapted Marc's answer, as well as using `MatDialogRef#backdropClick` to listen for click events to the backdrop.

Initially, the dialog will have the configuration option `disableClose` set as `true`. This ensures that the `esc` keypress, as well as clicking on the backdrop will not cause the dialog to close.

Afterwards, subscribe to the `MatDialogRef#backdropClick` method (which emits when the backdrop gets clicked and returns as a `MouseEvent`).

Anyways, enough technical talk. Here's the code:

```ts
openDialog() {
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, { disableClose: true });
  /*
     Subscribe to events emitted when the backdrop is clicked
  */
  dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => {
    // Close the dialog
    dialogRef.close();
  })

  // ...
}
```

Alternatively, this can be done in the dialog component:

```ts
export class DialogComponent {
  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>) {
    dialogRef.disableClose = true;
    /*
      Subscribe to events emitted when the backdrop is clicked
    */
    dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => {
      // Close the dialog
      dialogRef.close();
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: A warning for people using input fields with autocomplete. Using the HostListener closes the dialog when you close the auto-complete list.

Comment: You would also need to handle unsubscribing from the backdropClick Observable otherwise you'll introduce a memory leak.

Comment: I added @HostListener('window:keyup.escape') but I press ESC and it closes all modals... Can I bind the listner to the latest opened modal? I just want close one modal each time with ESC. DisableClose is set to true.

Comment: Why does setting disableClose on the config also then remove the ability to close the dialog using a button click?

Answer (score 9):

How about playing with these two properties?

> **disableClose:** boolean - Whether the user can use escape or clicking on the backdrop to close the modal.
>
> **hasBackdrop:** boolean - Whether the dialog has a backdrop.
>
> https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api

Comment: setting hasBackdrop to false removes the blackening of area outside the dialog

Comment: Worked with Angular 9. 'hasBackdrop' does not let the user to interact with other outside elements. disableClose does not allow the user to close the dialog with outside click or escape key.

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
[config]="{backdrop: 'static'}"
```

to the modal code.