# Prevent closing of Angular Material Dialog when escape button is pressed but allow closing when backdrop is clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

By default, when the <kbd>esc</kbd> button is pressed, the dialog closes. However, I don't want this intended behaviour.

What I would like to happen is to prevent closing when the <kbd>esc</kbd> button is pressed but still allow a click on the backdrop to close the dialog. How can this be done?

I've tried something like this. However, it doesn't work:

```ts
openEditDialog() {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditPlaceDialogComponent, {
    width: '90%',
    height: '720px'
  });

  dialogRef.keydownEvents().subscribe(e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      e.preventDefault();
      dialogRef.disableClose = false;
    }
  });

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log('The dialog was closed');
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable click outside of angular material dialog area to close the dialog (With Angular Version 4.0+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772852/disable-click-outside-of-angular-material-dialog-area-to-close-the-dialog-with)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the `disableClose` option of `MatDialogConfig`. Pass it in as the second parameter of `MatDialog#open`:

```ts
openDialog() {
  this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, { disableClose: true });
  // ...
}
```

This should prevent <kbd>esc</kbd> from closing the dialog.

---

**EDIT:** I managed to solve what you asked for by adapting Marc's answer (as a comment on my answer), as well as using `MatDialogRef#backdropClick` to listen for click events to the backdrop.

Initially, the dialogue will have `disableClose` set as `true`. This ensures that the `esc` keypress, as well as clicking on the backdrop will not cause the dialogue to close.

Afterwards, subscribing to the `MatDialogRef#backdropClick` method (which emits when the backdrop gets clicked and returns as a `MouseEvent`).

Anyways, enough technical talk. Here's the code:

```ts
openDialog() {
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditPlaceDialogComponent, { disableClose: true /* Your other config options here */ });
  /*
     Subscribe to events emitted when the backdrop is clicked
     NOTE: Since we won't actually be using the `MouseEvent` event, we'll just use an underscore here
     See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41086381 for more info
  */
  dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(_ => {
    // Close the dialog
    dialogRef.close();
  })

  // ...
}
```

[Stackblitz demo (click on "Open fourth dialog" to test it out!)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dialog-disable-close-so)

Comment: thank you for giving me an answer. The case that esc is disable but click outside is enable. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @通りすがりのおっさん I've managed to work it out. Check the Stackblitz demo!

Answer (score 0):

**Below Solution works for me:**

[image]

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig

```
    const dialogProperty= {
      disableClose: true,
      width: '600px',
      backdropClass: 'transparent',
      data: {data: userDetails}
    }
    this.submitModelRef = this._matDialog.open(SaveDetailsDialogComponent, dialogProperty);
```