# Pressing escape key closes the MatDialog instead of MatSelect options dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular12

We are using `mat-select` on a `mat-dialog` popup. If we open the `mat-select` to select options and then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, it closes the popup instead of `mat-select` options dropdown.

We are on version `12.1.4` for `Angular / Cdk / Material`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-54r4vt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

this is duplicated Question, you can find old question from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010064/prevent-closing-of-angular-material-dialog-when-escape-button-is-pressed-but-all),

also for answering this you can use `disableClose` when try to open the `MatDialogConfig`.
however, you need to add code for enabling closing when click on the backdrop to close the dialog.

```
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditPlaceDialogComponent, { disableClose: true /* Your other config options here */ });
  /*
     Subscribe to events emitted when the backdrop is clicked
     NOTE: Since we won't actually be using the `MouseEvent` event, we'll just use an underscore here
     See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41086381 for more info
  */
  dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(_ => {
    // Close the dialog
    dialogRef.close();
  })
```