# To close first dialogue window by the 2nd dialogue window in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

**Scenario:** I have an component called `add-customer` which i am displaying in an dialogue  window by clicking an button called `Add`as shown in below image.

[image]

Here i have 2 buttons `1)Save` and `2)Cancel`

On clicking `Cancel` button one more dialogue window comes as shown in below image.

[image]

Here in the new dialogue window again i have two buttons called `1)Discard` and `2)Cancel`

On clicking `Cancel` the new window will close and the `add-customer` component will remain same as shown in below image.

[image]

**Here my requirement are:**

1) On clicking `dicard` button i want to close both the dialogue windows(mean i want to close two pop-up windows).

2) Here the `add-customer` component is closing when we are clicking outside the dialogue window,but i want it to be closed only on clicking `discard` button only.

I have tried by giving two different `dialogRef` for `discard` and `cancel` buttons. No result. Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-zc7xjp?file=app/delete/delete.component.ts) link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this,

Import `MatDialog`

```
import {MatDialogRef,MatDialog} from '@angular/material';
```

Inject in constructor

```
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog,..){}
```

And the cancelN method should be

```
public cancelN(): void { 
    this.dialog.closeAll();
}
```

**Note:** It will close all opened dialog(s)

Comment: It's working fine, thank you very much. But Is it possible fulfill my 2nd requirement??

Comment: Can you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772852/disable-click-outside-of-angular-material-dialog-area-to-close-the-dialog-with)?

Comment: Okay let me try.

Answer (score 2):

I am just posting this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-rmitsj?file=app/demo/demo.component.ts) example, so that it would be helpful for next visitors.