# Confirm message before closing material dialog accidentally in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-6

How can i use of **beforeClose()** method to show a confirmation message before closing the material dialog ?

```
this.dialogRef.beforeClose().subscribe(result => {
      var cn = confirm('You have begun editing fields for this user. 
                        Do you want to leave without finishing?')
      console.log(cn);

    })
```

Comment: You can't. The `beforeClosed` stream is used to hook on closing start, meaning the modal is already closing. If you want to cancel the closing, you will have to implement your own method. Maybe `canDeactivate` guards can help you, otherwise simply prevent the user from leaving.

Comment: Instead open a snackbar asking for confirmation, and if snackbar action is selected, then perform action accordingly.

Comment: you can ask the user about confirmation before calling the `.close` method!

Comment: @Ashish Is [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z2ot9e) what you wanted?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale  i am asking for the situation if the user hit the refresh button or click outside of the dialog.

Comment: yes, have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772852/disable-click-outside-of-angular-material-dialog-area-to-close-the-dialog-with

Comment: @PrashantPimpale to ask from the user I've already implemented this code on Close button click event.

`onCloseDialog(): void { 
  
    if (this.userDetailsForm.dirty || this.userDetailsForm.touched) {
      var cn = confirm('You have begun editing fields for this user. Do you want to leave without finishing?')
      console.log(cn);
      if(cn)
      {
        this.dialogRef.close('Discard');
      }
    }else
    {
      this.dialogRef.close('Discard');
    }

  }`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale thanks for the link but it is not going to help out here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you want the `window.confirm` on the following things :

- if  user hit the refresh button, or
- click outside of the dialog

According to [referrence link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772852/disable-click-outside-of-angular-material-dialog-area-to-close-the-dialog-with) shared in comments,

 i have implemented a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dialog-example-beforeclose?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**, which uses `@HostListener`
Code for **`esc`**, and **`refresh`** :

```
@HostListener('window:keyup.esc') onKeyUp() {
    let cn = confirm('Sure ?')
    if (cn) {
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
  }

@HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"]) unloadHandler(event: Event) {
      console.log('event:', event);
      event.returnValue = false;
}
```

And in `ConfirmationDialog` component, handle `backDropClick()` as

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dialogRef.disableClose = true;
  this.dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(_ => {
    let cn = confirm('Sure ?')
    if (cn) {
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
  })
}
```

**Application Code :**  https://stackblitz.com/edit/dialog-example-beforeclose?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks buddy, this is the right answer. `window:beforeunload` has helped me out here to achieve my solution.

Comment: can't we override the default message of  `window:beforeunload` event ?

Comment: @AshishKumar yup, that was the problem with my case, i tried but was unable to produce my message on reload confirm box. So i thought let it be the same as confirm box was visible on reload.

Answer (score 4):

> you can prevent to close `dialog` from click `outside` or `esc`using `disableClose: true`

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal },
      scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.close(),
      disableClose: true //for diabled close dialog
    });
```

**You can use `confirmation` dialog with below code :**

```
 onNoClick(): void {
      var cn = confirm('You have begun editing fields for this user. Do you want to leave without finishing?');
       console.log(cn);
       if(cn){

    this.dialogRef.close();
       }
  };
  onOKClick(): void {
      var cn = confirm('You have begun editing fields for this user. Do you want to leave without finishing?');
       console.log(cn);
       if(cn){

    this.dialogRef.close();
       }
  };
```

HTML Code :

```
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="onOKClick()" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

> reference Link: [link1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-dialog-beforeclose-bug-n7yfwn?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.html), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772852/disable-click-outside-of-angular-material-dialog-area-to-close-the-dialog-with)

Comment: it'll not work when you'll refresh the page, my main issue was with refreshing of page if mat dialog is already opened . @Abhishek has given the right answer by using of `window:beforeunload` browser event with `@HostListener`. i also used to thought `beforeunload` will not work with material dialog. 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53499314/10288376)