# Angular: Disable clicking outside a dialog

Tags: angular

I want that it is not possible to click outside a dialog (nothing should happens).

I tried the followings that do not works for me:

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
   disableClose: true
});
```

or

```
this.dialogRef.disableClose = true
this.dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(_ => {
  this.dialogRef.close();
})
```

But when i click outside the opened dialog the main window reatcs.

Anybody know how I can solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable click outside of angular material dialog area to close the dialog (With Angular Version 4.0+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772852/disable-click-outside-of-angular-material-dialog-area-to-close-the-dialog-with)

Answer (score 0):

Thx. I added

```js
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TrackDialogComponent, {
  hasBackdrop: true,
});
```