# How to close Angular Material Dialog by clicking outside of the dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, modal-dialog

I have tried for hours to close the modal by clicking outside.
Clicking the X Button already works, but for outside clicks nothing has helped so far.
I tried with hasBackDrop and several other things, but nothing has worked out.

Open Button TS

```
<div class="">
  <button (click)="openModal()"/>Open</button>
</div>
```

Open Button HTML

```
export class NavbarAddFundsComponent{
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  openModal(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddFundsModalComponent);
  }
}
```

Modal HTML

```
<div class="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center">
  <div class="min-w-[90%] lg:min-w-[1000px] h-[600px] bg-nf-500">
    <div class="flex justify-end">
      <button mat-mini-fab autofocus="false" (click)="closeModal()"
              class="mt-3 mr-3 cursor-pointer text-primary-500 font-semibold text-3xl">&times;
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="relative bottom-2 text-primary-500 text-center font-semibold text-3xl relative">Modal</div>
      <div
        class="w-full lg:w-[350px] h-20 lg:h-[80%] lg:mt-0 mt-5 pt-5 lg:pt-0 lg:ml-4 ml-0 lg:pl-4 pl-0 border-t-2 lg:border-l-2 lg:border-t-0 border-neutral-500">
        <div class="bg-blue-200 w-full h-full"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Modal TS

```
export class AddFundsModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClientService, private fb: FormBuilder, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddFundsModalComponent>) {
  }
  closeModal() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable click outside of angular material dialog area to close the dialog (With Angular Version 4.0+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772852/disable-click-outside-of-angular-material-dialog-area-to-close-the-dialog-with)

Comment: @PhilippMeissner unfortunately not. I don't know by default ESC Key works for me but the hasBackdrop not. I solved it now by an extra div wrapper with h-full, w-full and then stopPropagation to prevent modal by clicking inside the modal.

Comment: Your code shows you are *not* passing in an option, therefore no `disableClose` value. Have you tried setting it?!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="absolute h-full w-full" (click)="closeModal()">
    <div class="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center">
        <div class="min-w-[90%] lg:min-w-[1000px] h-[600px] bg-nf-500" 
        (click)="handleClick($event)">
.
.
.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
  closeModal() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  handleClick(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).